# Why React native navigation loads all components at the same time?

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I am using react native navigation v2 by wix. I have a welcome screen with login screen and register. I start the startAuth.js from `App.js`. There are two tabs with login and register.

[image: Welcome screen]

But as soon as app starts the componentWillMount methods runs in the register screen but yet i am at login tab.

[image: Welcome Tabs]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`react-native-navigation`'s Tab does not support lazy loading. But there are two special lifecyle functions where you can put your logic when component appear or disappear on screen

- `componentDidAppear()`: called each time this component appears on screen
- `componentDidDisappear()`: called each time this component disappears from screen

https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/screen-lifecycle

There is also a discussion about topic https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/1250

Comment: Handled by lifecycles methods. Thank you.